# How to use Apache Olingo behind a proxy

Tags: java, apache, proxy, odata, olingo

I can successfully reach following OData-service using different browsers and also using Postman even so I am behind a proxy: 
    `String SERVICE_ROOT =` http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/

However, using Apache Olingo in Java I am not able to access this service.

JVM parameters like `-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=http-proxy.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080` allow me to perform basic URL functions, like retrieving HTTP status codes (google returns `200`). Nevertheless, access of the OData-Service using an ODataClient is not possible (code below). No errors are thrown.

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
ODataServiceDocumentRequest request = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getServiceDocumentRequest(SERVICE_ROOT);
ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientServiceDocument> response = request.execute();
```

I tried using the proxy capabilities within Olingo, however without any success:

```
client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new ProxyWrappingHttpClientFactory(URI.create("http://http-proxy.example.com:8080")));
```

What am I doing wrong, what options do I have left?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind an NTLM proxy you can try with NTLMAuthHttpClientFactory.

```
NTLMAuthHttpClientFactory ntlm = new NTLMAuthHttpClientFactory(username, password, workstation, domain);
client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(ntlm);
```

In case that doesn't work, you can try with **cntlm**. Install it, change username, password, domain and proxy in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini` and then invoke `net start cntlm`.
Use this for Olingo:

```
client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new ProxyWrappingHttpClientFactory(URI.create("http://localhost:3128")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved the problem by myself. Nevertheless I accepted your answer, because I really appreciated your input. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue and while looking for a solution I stumbled on your question. The approach suggested above solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
URI uri;
String scheme = "http";
        try {
            uri = new URI  (scheme,null,host,port,null,null,null);


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw(e);
        }
        HttpClientFactory clientProxy = new ProxyWrappingHttpClientFactory(uri,userName,password );

        client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(clientProxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved the problem by myself. Within VM arguments I now only have

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Further I defined a proxy config only within the application:

```
    client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
    client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(
            new ProxyWrappingHttpClientFactory(URI.create("http-prox.example.com:8080")));
```

This worked for me. :)